# Log HTTP Header redirects, ideally in Firefox

Tags: firefox, http-headers

I'm attempting to diagnose a specific failing test case in a legacy X-Cart installation, and determining program flow from reading the PHP source is non-trivial.  I need to be able to see what redirects occur and when, ideally in a sequential log, IE:

[timestamp] domain.com/cart.php?mode=checkout
[timestamp] paypal.com/magic?afoot&this=sorcery
[timestamp] domain.com/cart.php?mode=soulcrushingdespair

I've Googled to no avail.  If anyone knows how to log redirects in this way, or even similar ways, I would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Live HTTP Headers, which is an add-on you can download the usual way.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't find this.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug also does a great job of this.

Comment: Firebug wasn't catching the redirects at the time. I suspect it's a versioning-related bug, because it's working in Firebug now without issues. Fortunately, I did manage to get the data needed to apply my fixes from Pyroscope back in August. :)

Comment: It was more to help others facing the same problem. Better late than never as they say :)